# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $f(x) = -\int_1^{2/x} 2t^22^2dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Let $y=f(x) = -\int_1^{2/x} 2t^22^2dt$. $(t>0)$

Find the angle that $f^{-1}(x)$ make with $x$-axis.

In the book where I find this question, it was solved with that:

$f(2) = 0; f^{-1}(0)=2 \Rightarrow (f^{-1}){'}(0) = 1/f'(2)$

$f'(x) = \frac{2}{x^2}\frac{8}{x^2}2^\frac{2}{x} \therefore f'(2) = 2 \therefore (f^{-1}){'}(0) = 1/2 \therefore \theta=\tan^{-1} (1/2) $.

My problem is that I think it is not the angle with x-axis. the angle with x must be where $f^{-1}(x) = 0$ where it meets (intersects) $x$-axis. the point given in question is where it meets with $y$-axis. Am I right? If I am right, How to answer the question?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying after you provided the book's solution.  However, the angle between two functions $h$ and $g$ at $x_0$ is defined to be the angle between the tangent lines of $h$ and $g$ at $x_0$.  So here, $h = 0$ and $g = f^{-1}(x)$ and $x_0 = 0$

Comment: @KolosovPetro Pedantic.  He clearly means $dt$ and you should just say that than asking the question rhetorically.

Comment: Yes, haven't noticed that in title is correct version

Comment: @DionelJaime I mean $f^{-1} (0)$ is where $f^{-1}$ intersects y axis. not x axis. we want to find $x_0$ such that $f^{-1} (x_0) = 0$ and then find the angle at point $(x_0 ,0)$......... Not  at the point $(0,2)$. Am I wrong? (Sorry for my English, English is not my native language)

Comment: "angle with $x$" should be "angle with $x$-axis"

Comment: The book has given you the slope of the inverse function at x = 0 and hence the angle with the x axis at this point. I agree though, without the solution the question is impossible to interpret.